# How to determine css's class with if statement

Tags: asp.net

```
<div class="<%#((int)Eval("Cevaplanma_Sayisi")>0) ? "divcevaplanmasayisiozel" : "divcevaplanmasayisinormal" %>">
```

my code is above.the code runs when I use access database but it doesnt run with sqlserver2008 where is the error.it says when I runs the code invalid exception handled

Comment: What exactly was the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class='<%#(((int)Eval("Cevaplanma_Sayisi"))>0) ? "divcevaplanmasayisiozel" : "divcevaplanmasayisinormal" %>'>
```

The first problem is that you need to convert the `object` value of "Cevaplanma_Sayisi" into  `int`.

The second problem is that you must wrap the `Eval` statement within `'` and `'`, otherwise you get malformed html.

Comment: You don't need the extra brackets. Conversion would happen properly without the extra brackets.

Comment: no it has still error.I do already conversation.the error is that invalidcast exception was unhandled